# haxe Incrementing class ID with an autoBuild macro

Tags: macros, haxe

I'm trying to use an autoBuild macro on my Component class so that every class extending Component get an incrementing ID (0, 1, 2, 3...), the problem is that it seems haxe caches some files, so when recompiling some classes won't get rebuilt, so let's say some already built classes have ID 0, 1 and 2. Now I create some new classes and they will also get ID 0, 1 and 2 because the already built classes arent processed so they don't increment the ID. So I end up with some classes with the same ID in the generated code.

The code I use with the autoBuild macro is this:

```
#if (macro)
public static function build():Array<Field>
{
    var pos = Context.currentPos();

    var c = macro : {
        override function get_index()
        {
            return $v{componentCounter};
        }

        public static inline var INDEX = $v{componentCounter};
    };

    componentCounter++;

    switch (c)
    {
        case TAnonymous(fields):
            return Context.getBuildFields().concat(fields);
        default:
            throw 'unreachable';
    }
}
#end

public static var componentCounter = 0;
```

Is there any way to make something like this work?

Comment: I would probably store the numbers already used elsewhere, in a file.

Comment: Why do you need these IDs in the first place?

Comment: @Gama11 to retrieve components in an efficient way, var physic = world.getComponent(entity, PhysicComponent); becomes var physic = this.world.components[2][entity];

Comment: What about a `Map` or `HashMap` and some predefined, constant IDs? Map/HashMap is still very efficient. Or [GUIDs/UUIDs](http://api.haxe.org/cs/system/Guid.html), or something equivalent, to get rid of this "incrementing" requirement.